# docker add extract to custom directory

Tags: docker

A `docker add` will nicely extract the supplied compressed file into the directory specified in the zip/tar file

**How can I extract it into a different directory?**

Eg. if the file extracts to `/myfile` but I would prefer `/otherFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't believe there's any way to do this just using the `ADD` instruction. `ADD` supports a target directory obviously, like `ADD ["<src>", "<dest>"]` however it's still going to extract into the dir you have in the tar within that.

2 options, either rename the dir in the tar or do a `RUN mv myfile otherfile` after adding.

Is there a specific reason you need it to be named something in particular?

Comment: just for convenience

Comment: AFAIK ADD then RUN creates 2 layers, and with a `mv` in the run the later layer will delete the original locations and add them else where. This appears to lead to potentially wasted space used by the container overall.

Answer (score -1):

Think about this scenario where you build a tomcat image,

ADD apache-tomcat-8.0.48.tar.gz /opt

This cmd will extract the tar to /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.48 , if you don't like the long folder name(apache-tomcat-8.0.48)  then the requirement happens.